# Iterative display of objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, iterator

I find that when I iteratively render a collection of objects, say, comments, rails also lists the addresses of the objects. For example, my view may contain the following:

```
<h3>Comments</h3>
<% if @blogpost.comments.any? %>
  <%= @blogpost.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= render :partial => "comment", :locals => {:comment => comment} %>
  <% end %>  
<% end %>
```

The view often shows this:

```
<h3>Comments</h3> 
  <p>comment #2</p> 
  <p class="post-info"> >> Example User,  about 1 hour ago. </p> 

  <p>this is user 1's comment on user 5's article</p> 
  <p class="post-info"> >> Example User,  2 days ago. </p> 

#&lt;Comment:0xb6f91968&gt;#&lt;Comment:0xb6f9016c&gt;
```

As you can see, there are a couple of address listings for the objects, which I would prefer not to have in the view.  Is there a way to suppress this output?  Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove **=** from `<%= @blogpost.comments.each do |comment| %>`

when we add = in <% %> rails will execute erb code and render the output in html.

Comment: @Ander, you should click the green tick under the @Naren's answer and accept it. It's way of the land here on StackOverflow and keeps this full of motivated answer-giving folks!

Answer (score 0):

Also, you don't really need all of this code.
You can left only these two lines to render `'comment'` partial for `@blogpost.comments` collection:

```
<h3>Comments</h3>
<%= render @blogpost.comments %>
```

and Rails will do the trick.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html